# Displaying proper date format depending on culture

Tags: asp.net, javascript, culture, date-format

I am using a control for a popup calendar date picker.  This uses a javascript function, SetText, to set the textbox to the given date.  I can't change anything in the calendar control itself but I can override the SetText function.  The SetText javascript just takes the TextBox name and the date value in string format and sets the TextBox to the string.

The problem: 
I need to display the date in the format "April 30".

Easy to do.  Use getMonth() and getDate() where I can parse the information from there.

Now, I need to make sure this shows correctly for different cultures.  For example, the UK shows dates as "30 April".  Since the code-behind(c#) could be sending the date in the UK format how do I know in the javascript that they're using UK(dd/mm/yyyy) and not US(mm/dd/yyyy)?
The browsers navigator language could be set to one setting while the server is set to another to cause a January 4 as April 1 mismatch.

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer but the dojo JS library has an excellent date localization package:  http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojo.date.locale.format

Comment: The Datejs library includes a host of date functions that let you format and parse dates in a variety of formats and using date format strings. http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 4):

You are using the Microsoft Ajax Framework, this framework defines a set of "[client-side type extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397506.aspx)" which provide added functions or "extensions" to the JavaScript base types.

The [Date Type Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310850.aspx) is what you're looking for, specifically the [Date.parseLocale function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397521.aspx).

With this function you can parse a string, using a given format.

You can synchronize your server-side and client-side culture by setting the [ScriptManager.EnableScriptGlobalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablescriptglobalization.aspx) property to true, and use the Date.parseLocale function without specifying any format.

Give a look to this article:

- [Walkthrough: Globalizing a Date by Using Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386581.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

See [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) and related functions.

Comment: But that gives "Thursday, April 30, 2009 4:57:00 PM "  I could chop the front and back off the string but it will not always be day first with year and time in the back will it?  I've looked into this before but didn't find the answer

Comment: toLocaleDateString gets you closer at least. I should also point out the locale difference is really only prevalent with numerical dates (11/22/09 could be Nov 12 or Dec 11), but when you use a month name or abbrev, the meaning should be clear anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the backend, why not just send a timestamp and push it into `Date` object?

As for formatting on the client side, since I was already using Dojo, I solved this problem by using `dojo.date.locale.format`.  It was completely painless.

- Locale is detected automatically or can be set arbitrarily.
- Shorthand format options (e.g.: long short)
- Data selectors (e.g.: time, date)
- Ability to specify an arbitrary date/time pattern (probably not application to this application, but still useful).

Tutorial: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/date/locale
API doc: 
http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojo.date.locale.format
Date format descriptions: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1):

Three things you could use:

1)  [toLocaleString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLocaleString.asp) - As suggested already.  The problem with this is when sending a string of "4/1/2009" this can result in a couple things.  January 4 or April 1.

2)  navigator.language and [navigator.systemLanguage](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_nav_systemlanguage.asp) - After you get the date string you can check to see what language the system is in and parse the date from there.  The problem with this and solution 1 is what if you have a UK server and the browsers machine is US.  You will have the code behind sending April 1 as 1/4/2009 where the javascript will read the string as whatever language the clients browsers is.  So, UK server and US browser will give you a wrong result.

3)  Use Code Behinds Culture - Create a variable in your javascript that when the page loads, it will call a function in your code behind that returns `this.Page.Culture` from there, you will know what culture the string is being sent back as.  This will eliminate the mismatch that the first two solutions can cause.  It will take a little extra work to make sure it's displayed correctly but at least you will be able to use the string without having the possibility of mismatching cultures.

Answer (score 1):

[toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) would be a better solution than [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) for your problem as it doesn't include the time (as you only are requesting the date).

Answer (score 1):

The open-source JavaScript library Date.js has some great methods for formatting dates, as well as it supports a bunch of languages:

Date.js at Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

If you want nicely formatted dates / times, you can just pass [a formatting string](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) (nearly identical to those used in .NET Framework) into any Date object's `.toString()` method.

It also has a whole set of cultures which allow you to simply include the appropriate script for that culture.

If you want to manage that yourself (as we do in our apps), you can find resources which give you the list of appropriate resource strings for a given culture.  Here's one that shows proper formatting strings for a ton of cultures: http://www.transactor.com/misc/ranges.html

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ASP.NET then you may also be using ASP.NET Ajax. If so, there are two properties on the [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager_members.aspx) that are of use to you:

[EnableScriptLocalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablescriptlocalization.aspx) - Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the ScriptManager control renders localized versions of script files.

[EnableScriptGlobalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablescriptglobalization.aspx) - Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the ScriptManager control renders script that supports parsing and formatting of culture-specific information.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="AjaxManager" runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
            EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
```

When you enable both of these (set to true) then ASP.NET Ajax extenders etc. should automatically be localised into the culture specified in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization 
       fileEncoding="utf-8" 
       requestEncoding="utf-8" 
       responseEncoding="utf-8" 
       culture="en-GB" 
       uiCulture="en-GB" />  
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For instance, setting this will localise the [AjaxControlToolkit Calendar](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) into your specificed culture.

Even if you are NOT using ASP.NET Ajax adding a ScriptManager and enabling localisation will give you a useful javascript variable called `__cultureInfo` that contains a JSON array of localised formate, such as currencies, dates etc.

```
"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2029,"IsReadOnly":true},"DateSeparator":"/","FirstDayOfWeek":1,"CalendarWeekRule":0,"FullDateTimePattern":"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss","LongDatePattern":"dd MMMM yyyy","LongTimePattern":"HH:mm:ss","MonthDayPattern":"dd MMMM","PMDesignator":"PM","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using Datejs as

- In codebehind(aspx.cs) I get the culture for an employee and add the appropriate js to the header as

> string path =
>   "http://datejs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/date-"
>   + GetCulture() + ".js"; Helper.AddJavaScript(this, path);

(in your case you can get the culture from navigator.systemLanguage (or navigator.browserLanguge etc) and add a script tag to the header with src attribute pointing to the appropriate path)

- On the client-side I use

> d.toString(Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortDate)

where d is any date object
(I tried using Date.today().toShortDateString() but it was throwing exception. (the CultureInfo JSON object had a different structure than what the function expects).